# hive query to map keys to multiple values

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hql

I have a table with a structure similar to the one below:

```
|C1|C2|C3|
|K1|V1|??|
|K1|V2|??|
|K1|V3|??|
|K2|V2|??|
```

I need to write a query that checks if the key(lets say K1) maps to a specific value in any row (say V2). If it does the value in column C3 is taken as 1 otherwise its 0.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The folloiwng query should give the results you want.  The subquery identifies all `C1` values which map to a certain value in `C2` at least once.  If so, then we render the `C3` values as 1, otherwise we show 0.

```
SELECT
    t1.C1,
    t1.C2,
    CASE WHEN t2.C1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS C3
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT C1
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY C1
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN C2 = 'V1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
) t2
    ON t1.C1 = t2.C1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Although I think the join should probably be a left join.

Comment: @parth Let me update the query then.  I don't know why I got downvoted.